# MS Edge images not respecting flex basis

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I have a peculiar case of Edge not behaving like any other browser with it's flexbox. Even IE11 is handling this nearly the same as Chrome and Firefox.

[The example codepen here.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XaWwgK)

Here's the *intended result* that works across basically all browsers:
[image: Intended Result]

Instead, this is *what is happening* in Microsoft Edge:
[image]

It's like the images don't respect the bounds of the 30% flex basis. If I change the <img> tag to a <div> and place the <img> within it, it fixes the problem somewhat. It causes me other issues in the design that aren't shown here if that is done, so I'd like to avoid it if I can. It shouldn't need to have a wrapper div.

**What's really strange is I can't find anything documenting why this issue might be happening.** I've looked through the list of flexbugs and nothing seems to apply.

**Html**:

```
<div class="sections-container">
<section class="content-tiles-section">
    <div class="content-tiles-content">
        <div class="content-tiles">
                <div>
                    <img class="content-tile-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/431x288">
                    <div class="content-tile-content">
                        <h4>
                            <a href="#">
                                Title Link
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="content-tile-paragraph p-like">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at lorem justo. Maecenas eget dui est. In cursus. 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="content-tile-link" href="#">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img class="content-tile-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/398x266">
                    <div class="content-tile-content">
                        <h4>
                            <a href="#">
                                Title Link
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="content-tile-paragraph p-like">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at lorem justo. Maecenas eget dui est. In cursus. 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="content-tile-link" href="#">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img class="content-tile-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/462x308">
                    <div class="content-tile-content">
                        <h4>
                            <a href="#">
                                Title Link
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="content-tile-paragraph p-like">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at lorem justo. Maecenas eget dui est. In cursus. 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="content-tile-link" href="#">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img class="content-tile-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/505x335">
                    <div class="content-tile-content">
                        <h4>
                            <a href="#">
                                Title Link
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="content-tile-paragraph p-like">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at lorem justo. Maecenas eget dui est. In cursus. 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="content-tile-link" href="#">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img class="content-tile-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x300">
                    <div class="content-tile-content">
                        <h4>
                            <a href="#">
                                Title Link
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="content-tile-paragraph p-like">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at lorem justo. Maecenas eget dui est. In cursus. 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="content-tile-link" href="#">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img class="content-tile-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x333">
                    <div class="content-tile-content">
                        <h4>
                            <a href="#">
                                Title Link
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="content-tile-paragraph p-like">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean at lorem justo. Maecenas eget dui est. In cursus. 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="content-tile-link" href="#">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

**SCSS**:

```
.sections-container .content-tiles-section {
  background-color: #05225E;
  .content-tiles-content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1180px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0;
    > h2 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
  .content-tiles {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    > div {
      margin: 10px 0;
      flex: 0 1 30%;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-top-right-radius: 15px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      .content-tile-image {
        flex: 0 1 100%;
        width: 100%;
        border-top-right-radius: 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
      }
      .content-tile-content {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        padding: 12px 24px;
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
      .content-tile-link {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        padding: 12px 24px 24px 24px;
      }
    }
  }
}
.our-services .sections-container {
  .our-services-main-content-section {
    padding: 35px 15px 75px 15px;
    .intro {
      color: #005596;
      max-width: 900px;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 2rem;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
  .content-tiles-section {
    background-color: #a40356;
  }
}
```

Any insight is highly appreciated!

Comment: Your codepen is working on my microsoft edge 15.

Comment: Edge and Chrome render the same here.

Comment: @Michael_B Oh wow, they do. I must have an outdated version of edge on my work PC. I need to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of edge is outdated. I don't have mine set to automatically update, so it's in a 2015 version.

Version: **20.10240**
EdgeHTML Version: **12.10240**